# How to fix connection with database in CakePHP with MAMP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, mamp

I want to connect to CakePHP3.77 with MySQL 5.7.25 in MAMP.
I cannot connect with database named cake_youtube_db.

Error Message is this.

CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.
Connection to database could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

I did try create other users and put user and password. 
However they did not work.

**/config/app.php**

```
'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',

            //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'database' => 'cake_youtube_db',
```

SQL plugin is mysql_native_password.
I expect Database will be connected with my cakeapp.

Comment: I think MAMP usually uses a non-standard port number for MySQL, like 8889, so you would change `//'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',` to `'port' => 8889,`.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed, but It did not work well.

Comment: Do you use cakephp outside the mamp? Try change host to IP of mamp. Or why not use vagrant box like https://github.com/salines/vagrant-cakephp ?

Comment: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/youtube/bookmarker`
and bookmarker is Cake App which I want to develop.
If I cannot solve this within 3days, I am gonna use vagrant instead of MAMP.

Comment: Can you connect to the database using these credentials from the command line (`mysql -u root -h localhost ...`)?